# Confusion in creating UML diagram

Tags: uml

I am creating a UML diagram and i am bit confuse where to use `<<extend>>`, `<<use>>` and where to use `<<include>>` in my use case diagram.

Suppose user click on an edit link to  modify the details of it so what to use after click event `<<use>>` or `<<extend>>`..

Please help me on this .. please also tell the best tool use to create UML diagram.
At present I am using Edraw.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While modeling your business process through use cases, first of all, you need to go through requirement engineerng process [for dynamic design view]. In case of use case diagram, you may use

`<<extends>>` for generalization, alternate scenario of success or failure e.g. `receive phone call` may  extend `receive business phone call`

`<<uses>>` if one scenario requires other related scenario eg. `reserve book` may use `check membership status`

For further understanding about UML diagrams, you may follow following books:

```
1. Applying UML & Patterns - Craig Larman

2. UML distilled : Applying the standard object Modeling Language - Martin Fowler

3. The Unified Modeling Language User Guide - Booch et. al
```

For drawing of UML diagrams, you may use following software packages:

```
1. ArgoUML

2. Rational Rose
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use include if one use case cannot be done without the other one.
Use extend if the second use case is optional and the base use case can exist on its own.

For example:

- Use Case A: Drive with your car to vermont
- Use Case B: Wash your car
- Use Case C: Buy some fuel for your car
- A includes C => otherwise you can't drive
- B extends A => you can drive to vermont without washing your car before, but it would be nice.

Note: A included use-case always makes sense on it's own.

EDIT:
A simple but yet effective uml editor i am using quite a lot is [violet](http://alexdp.free.fr/violetumleditor/page.php)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into this question as well - it asks quite the same with a concrete example: [how to use use case relations - uml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385233/how-to-use-use-case-relations-uml/12401268#12401268)

I quite good general explanation can be found [here](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Learning+uml/Part+II+Structural+Modeling/Chapter+4.+Use-Case+Diagrams/4.4+Dependencies/).

Reading the other answers here, I have to emphasize that the direction of the dependency should not be confused: `receive business phone call` and `receive private phone call` would extend `receive phone call` as the first one would be more special than the latter one. An actor could 'receive a phone call' by 'receiving a business phone call'.

An <> dependency is understood more easily. Still the in the other answer here is not entirely correct: `Drive with your car to vermont` does not neccessarily include `Buy some fuel for your car` as the car could already have enough fuel. But `Buy some fuel for your car` would include `Pay for fuel` - otherwise you would have stolen it ;)

Generally you should model/draw only dependencies which are meaningful for understanding the Use Case System. It won't help anyone (but a teacher, perhaps) to draw all possible dependencies between the Use Cases.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you are doing well

include is required and shared between 2 or more activities, while extend is optional and doesn't need to be shared.
see these video:

1#: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkC7HKtiZC0&feature=plcp
2#: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1BDC709220824BE1&feature=plcp

and the best tool is Papyrus simply because it is open source

Comment: Thanks @Safa Eng, christian and sabre